# Long running request broke automatically in AppHarbor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, appharbor

I have a code running on appharbor, in which I stream some data to the client. Its a very long request-response ideally could be 30-40 minutes.

The content which gets streamed is non-bufferred, which means the response is not hold for a long but will be written asap and will continue until the specified time. I have mentioned the below code but the application failes after 10minutes of the response. Can someone please let me know whats wrong is happening here.

```
public class TestWaitResult : ActionResult
{
    int _timeToWait;
    object o = new object();
    TextWriter output;
    HttpResponseBase r;
    int _sleepTimer;
    public TestWaitResult(int timeToWait, int sleepTimer)
    {
        _timeToWait = timeToWait;
        _sleepTimer = sleepTimer;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = context.HttpContext.Response.BufferOutput = false;
        r = context.HttpContext.Response;
        output = context.HttpContext.Response.Output;
        while (r.IsClientConnected)
        {
            Log("Executing...");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(_sleepTimer * 1000);
            if ((_timeToWait = _timeToWait - _sleepTimer) <= 0)
            {
                Log("Timetowait exceeds");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Log(string message)
    {
        lock (o)
        {
            try
            {
                if (r.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    output.WriteLine("<br/>{0} : {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"), message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AppHarbor has a 120 second hard [request timeout as specified in the program policy](https://appharbor.com/page/programpolicy).

You should probably re-implement your task in a [background worker](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/background-workers) or similar and make the file available for download from S3.

Comment: I don't think so that the limit is 2minutes as i can see the response coming to me for 10 minutes and even 5 minutes and suddenly got broke. And what you mean by specifying the download from S3?